# Primary key violation issue using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate. A Service is exposed as a webservice. This service wil be called by 2 applications. The service method saves record into database.

```
ServiceClass.java:
------------------

//Here Transaction will start
public void saveRecord(SampleEntity entity){

someDAO.saveData(entity);

}


SomeDao.java
-----------------

public void saveData(SampleEntity entity){
  //record is saved using saveOrUpdate method
}
```

If `saveRecord` method is called by two applications `at a time` with same ID, `PK violation exception` is thrown.

Both the applications are sending the records with same ID.

As we are using `saveOrUpdate` it should update the record if it already exists.

Comment: You have to obtain existing entity from DB and update its values. If it does not exist (hibernate returns null) then you create it.

Comment: Do you manually set the id or is it generated by Hibernate ?

Comment: we r doing same thing but no use. My hunch is that, application one calls save method passing an entity, but before persisting the record into database second application will also make a call to save. obviously DB will not have the record as application one has not yet inserted the record.

Comment: we manually set the ID

Comment: "as we are using saveOrUpdate it should update the record if it already exists." - You are right, so you are doing something wrong. Without the actual code it is hard to tell, WHAT you are doing wrong.

Comment: if you are manually setting the id then you should synchronize the method that generate this id.

Comment: id is set and passed from the application which is calling the save method..

Comment: Why are you setting the ID manually? You may want to use an appropriate generator (maybe a custom generator, if needed).

Comment: nope...we cannot ..ids are application specific..

Comment: Can you show us how you generate/set the id ?

Comment: "*ids are application specific*", then you must use a custom generator. Otherwise, if you set them manually, then you will have face a terrible situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is in a transaction, the row will be locked (and the index not updated) until the transaction commits.  So it may look like two inserts with the same PK if the update happens before the commit.

Comment: A lot depends on how your applications are laid out. One idea would be to either put logic in the the save Service class that arbitrates stores (ensuring one completes before the update fires). Or put the actual save behind a facade that does this (probably cleaner). You could do something like save a static map of PKs in process (added on the way in and cleared on the way out). Probably want a synchronized map or block here to make this vaguely safe.